# While retrieving the dataStore.js object throws undefined in js file

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have created a `dataStore.js` object and tried to pass below string to object as below.
Getting undefined while console.log in Home.js, could someone please advise the issue here.

```
let dataStore = {
    globaldata1: {},
    globaldata2: {}
}

export { dataStore }
```

// profile.js

```
let datastore = require("../global/dataStore");

let myStr1 = "This is a string" ;
let myStr2 = "This is another string" ;
datastore.globaldata1 = myStr1;
datastore.globaldata2 = myStr2;
```

// home.js

```
let datastore = require("../global/dataStore");

let globalStr1 = datastore.globaldata1 ;
console.log("Print the data::"+globalStr1);

let globalStr2 = datastore.globaldata2  ;
console.log("Print the second data::"+globalStr2);
```

**Applied the same concept in my Cypress tests:**

Cypress version : **v10.2.0**

//dataStore.js

```
let dataStore = {
    globaldata: {}
}

export { dataStore }
```

//site.Cy.js file

```
let dataStore = require("../../../support/dataStore");
import "cypress-localstorage-commands";

describe('Verify the Global data saving', () => {

  context('Global data', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.restoreLocalStorage();
      cy.visit('/');
    });

   
    it('First get the text and Save globally', () => {
 
      cy.get('#companyNameDiv > span').invoke('text').then((text)=>{
         dataStore.globaldata = text;
         console.log("First test outcome:: " +dataStore.globaldata); // all good here
      });
    });

    it('Use that text in second test', () => {
      console.log("Yeh, global text in second test :: " +dataStore.globaldata );  // all good here
    });
  });
});
```

//another.Cy.js file

```
let dataStore = require("../../../support/dataStore");
import "cypress-localstorage-commands";

describe('Retrive another test file', () => {
  context('Retrive saved data in another test file', () => {

    it('Get the text', () => {
     console.log("Yeh, another test file:: " +dataStore.globaldata); 
     // here I am getting the text as undefined  ??
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking out the Cypress tests, with some slight mods for folder paths and different baseUrl.

Since Cypress v10 no longer has "Run all" option I also added a barrel spec called **all.cy.js** which allows running multiple specs and **also** enforces the order of the spec (which would be important for this to work).

The test worked ok in `cypress open` then selecting `all.cy.js` and also `cypress run --spec cypress/e2e/all.cy.js`.

**all.cy.js**

```js
import './site.cy.js'
import './another.cy.js'
```

**site.cy.js**

```js
let dataStore = require("../support/dataStore");
import "cypress-localstorage-commands";

describe('Verify the Global data saving', () => {

  context('Global data', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.restoreLocalStorage();
      cy.visit('http://example.com')
    });

   
    it('First get the text and Save globally', () => {
 
      // cy.get('#companyNameDiv > span').invoke('text').then((text)=>{
        const text = 'this is my text'
        dataStore.globaldata = text;
        console.log("First test outcome:: " +dataStore.globaldata); // all good here
      // });
    });

    it('Use that text in second test', () => {
      console.log("Yeh, global text in second test :: " +dataStore.globaldata );  // all good here
    });
  });
});
```

**another.cy.js**

```js
let dataStore = require("../support/dataStore");
import "cypress-localstorage-commands";

describe('Retrive another test file', () => {
  context('Retrive saved data in another test file', () => {

    it('Get the text', () => {
      console.log("Yeh, another test file:: " +dataStore.globaldata); 

      expect(dataStore.globaldata).to.eq('this is my text')   // ✅ passes
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you very much. But I apply similar approach in my cypress test and the second test file doesn't have the string value, it is always undefined.

Comment: By using Cypress task() I can handle that, but i would like to achieve the same by programitically using js capabilities ...

Comment: It should be possible - Can I see the Cypress details?

Comment: Sure will add that ....

Comment: Updated with Cypress test details

Comment: I have updated my question with cypress details, could you please a have look when you get a chance

Comment: Sure I already took a look - have modified the answer to show Cypress version that works for me. Maybe you have a different requirement for running the specs, if so let me know. Cheers.

Comment: Super, that is great way.

Comment: But we wont get the value if we run the js file individually right  ?

Comment: Hm sounds like magic :) Do you want to save as fixture rather than an in-memory dataStore?

Comment: Thank you but not interested in fixture Fody,  reasons 
```1. Fixture - not interested to store
2. localStorage - good option, but will get cleared in normal process
3. store as object - interested to pursue 
4. Another way is store in browser indexDB -- but bit clunky way to do it  
5. using cy.task()  - not interested 
6. using getters, setters method ...???  not sure whether it will retain ```

Comment: Yeah, most of those methods the data vanishes between runs, which means you need to run the specs in sequence as original pattern. If making two separate Cypress runs, disk is the only common media that I can think of.

Comment: Sounds like a whole other question...

Comment: @Could you please have a look, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73016858/how-can-we-login-to-system-with-multiple-users-during-parallel-run-in-cypress-te

Comment: @soccerway - This sounds similar to [Test a Socket.io Chat App using Cypress](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/test-socketio-chat-using-cypress/). The basic problem with running two users at the same time is coordinating actions between them. This article uses Socket.IO to do it, but if you don't have Socket.IO you can use a common API server (provided it accepts POST requests).

Answer (score 0):

It would seem the issue here is that you didn't properly capitalize your import.

Your export from dataStore.js is:

```
export { dataStore }
```

Where the S is capitalized, but in your Home.js:

```
const { datastore } = reqiure(...)
```

It doesn't have a capitalized S which would make the import undefined because dataStore.js doesn't export datastore, it exports dataStore